# How to change InstallShield controls properties dynamically?

Tags: controls, installshield, installscript

I have a custom dialog in my IS installer and I want to change some properties such as Height, Top etc. according to the text written in the text areas (on run-time).

Are there any InstallScript functions that handle those parameters (something like CtrlSetText for changing the text)?

Comment: What project type are you using?  InstallScript, Basic MSI or InstallScript MSI?

Comment: I want to change it through InstallScript

Comment: That didn't answer my question.  What project type are you using?  All three of those project types support InstallScript in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a Windows Installer project type, you can use temporary tables and data.  If you understand the underlying table schema you can use InstallScript to write a custom action that changes this during the installation.  For starters see:

[Q103295 : Dynamically Add and Remove Values from a Combo Box at Run Time](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q103295)